# Adding new dynamic properties

Tags: c#-4.0

we read in msdn we "Adding new dynamic properties" by using DynamicObject Class
 i write a following program

```
public class DemoDynamicObject : DynamicObject
{

}
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        dynamic dd = new DemoDynamicObject();
        dd.FirstName = "abc";
    }
}
```

But when i run this program it gives  runtime error :'DemoDynamicObject' does not contain a definition for 'FirstName' 
if we adding dynamic  property by using DynamicObject Class then why it can give this error
can anyone tell me reason and solution?

Answer (score 9):

When using DynamicObject as your base class, you should provide specific overrides to TryGetMember and TrySetMember to keep track of the dynamic properties you are creating (based on the [DynamicObject MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx)):

```
class DemoDynamicObject: DynamicObject
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary
        = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public override bool TryGetMember(
        GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string name = binder.Name;
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(
        SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        dictionary[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you just want to have a dynamic object that you can add properties to, you can simply use an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) instance, and skip the custom class inheriting from DynamicObject.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer resolved your issue, you should consider marking it the Accepted Answer. Thanks.